# Run an setup file (.exe) on mutiple machines remotely using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run an exe copied to a specified folder on all servers along with an argument list. This however is failing without any errors, file copy is working fine, however remote execution of the setup is failing.

The following is what I am writing.

Kindly suggest, any assistance would be appreciated.

```
$servers = Get-Content c:\temp\servers.txt

foreach ($server in $servers){
    "Processing $server"
    Copy-Item -Path "\\$serverA\utility$\Setup.exe" -Destination "\\$server\c$\temp\Setup.exe" -Force

    $copy_complete = Test-Path "\\$server\c$\temp\Setup.exe" 
    if ($copy_complete) {
        "copy successful"
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Start-Process 'c:\temp\Setup.exe'  -ArgumentList '/quiet /noreboot /enable_remote_assistance  /Exclude "Smart Tools agent","Profile Manager WMI Plugin","Personal vDisk"' }
        "$server completed"
    }
    else {
        "Failed copy, retry manually on $server"
    }
}
```

Comment: is PowerShell remoting enabled? if so what does `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { ls c:\}` return?

Comment: If you log on locally and run the `Start-Process` command what happens?

Comment: If i run it locally it works fine, the upgrade finishes successfully

Comment: Yes, ps remoting is enabled, the "ls c:\" returned directory listing for all the servers in sequence

Comment: what happens when you try `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Start-Process "\\$serverA\utility$\Setup.exe"  -ArgumentList '/quiet /noreboot /enable_remote_assistance  /Exclude "Smart Tools agent","Profile Manager WMI Plugin","Personal vDisk"' }` or you could add a `Start-Sleep -Seconds 3` right after `Copy-Item ...`

Comment: i had tried that initially, before i started copying the file over. It makes no difference still unable to get the exe to be executed. Also added the start-sleep after the file copy still no avail. the exe doesnt execute and no error is displayed

Comment: `Test-Path` and `Copy-Item` point to different files? Is this a typo?

Comment: Yep, that's just a typo for reference, i am pretty sure, i am calling the same file as copied, and it is working locally. anyways i'll amend the code snippet to avoid any confusion

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with the call operator (&)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
    $executable='c:\temp\Setup.exe'
    $arguments='/quiet /noreboot /enable_remote_assistance /Exclude "Smart Tools agent","Profile Manager WMI Plugin","Personal vDisk"'
    & $executable $arguments
}
```